# What is this symbol on the battery?

Tags: battery

[image]

What does this mean? It is one of the many symbols and logos on a phone battery.

I know it's not technically an Android question, but at least it's related, and I couldn't find a more suitable StackExchange site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this wikimedia commons site, it is Taiwan's official recycling symbol. Probably means the battery is recyclable.
[image]
https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Recycle_symbol_Taiwan.svg